# External GPS antenna for smart phones

Tags: audio, gps, cellphone

Is there a smartphone GPS boost or external GPS antenna commercially available for smartphones.
To hook up to smartphones via audio input for example?

Comment: To hook to audio input, you'd need a whole external GPS receiver. There's no way to stuff a GPS RF signal through.

Comment: GPS is 1575 MHz and audio is 20 Hz to 20 KHz, How is it even possible to hook up GPS antenna on audio port.?

Comment: Actually some smartphones used the audio wire (headset) as FM antenna (for FM radio reception) so the idea is not totally outlandish... but this is the wrong place to ask.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff where should i ask it please?

Comment: http://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ or http://superuser.com/. If you can formulate it as a sufficiently general/generic question you can go with the latter. If you want specific products, the former.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not going to be possible to connect a GPS antenna to the audio port.  You might be able to connect it to one of the test connectors on the back of the phone under the cover, but this is going to be highly dependent on the specific phone.  You may also run in to issues if you want to use an active GPS antenna, as the phone likely will not provide the required bias.